# How to perform action when assertion is failed in minitest

Tags: ruby, testing, assert, minitest

I am doing automation of api using minitest in ruby. If any assertion is getting failed, then I want to perform some sort of action. Is there anything I can do when `assert_equal()` is getting failed?

Comment: Please post the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

**assert_equal** compares two things. You can compare these things by yourself.
Like:

```
if a != b
  action
end
```

p.s. assert_equal do little more than just comparing(compare float/time/class/regex), you can look at his [source](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_equal).